# Batch Script: Extract number from a string

Tags: regex, string, batch-file, extract

I'm writing a batch script where I need to extract numbers from a string (which indicates the version of a file), so that I can compare it with another number.
Below is my script written so far

```
:: Over here I'm trying to extract number from the string , this isn't working
    for %%F in ("!name!\.." ) do (
    ::set "number=%%~nxF" |findstr /b /e /r "\"[0-9]*\"" 
    set res=%name:findstr /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$"
    echo !res!
    )
```

In the last two for loop I have implemented the extract number logic, but it just prints `The system cannot find the drive specified.`
If anybody could help me with this issue that would be a great help.

Comment: You cannot assign the output of a command using the SET command. That is what FOR /F is used for.

Comment: @Squashman 
ok I have replaced it with this `for %%f in ("!name!") do for /f %%n in ('echo %%f^|findstr /b /e /r "\"[0-9]*\""') do ( echo %%~n)` but it says incorrect syntax . I appreciate your help can you please suggest what went wrong here

Comment: `findstr` has not a full set of REGEX (only some very basics) and is unable to return a substring. It will always return the complete line. You have to use `for` with `tokens` and `delims`. Show us the filename, if you need help with it.

Comment: @Stephan Below are few file names
`001.firstquery.sql
011secondquery.sql
012.thirdquery.sql`

`.` is been used but it may or may not be there after a numerical ,so I think it can't be used as a delims

Comment: Numbers are three chars at the beginning of the name always?

Comment: @Stephan
No not necessary

Comment: ok, idea: `delims=aAbBcC...` (all valid chars for filenames except numbers). Ugly, but should work.

Comment: `findstr` can't be used to extract a substring. It always returns the complete string (line).